# How can I receive LogRecord with Netty?

Tags: netty

I have an application that is sendind LogRecord through TCp and I want to capture this logs. I`m new with Netty and after traying with some examples I can't read the LogRecord objects.

I tried obtaining the array of bytes to deserialize the object but I get errors. Someone can point me a good example or tip to consider.

Here is the code:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("socketChannelInitializer")
public class SocketChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    private static final ByteArrayDecoder DECODER = new ByteArrayDecoder();
    private static final ByteArrayEncoder ENCODER = new ByteArrayEncoder();

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("socketServerHandler")
    private ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter socketServerHandler;

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();

        // Add the text line codec combination first,
        pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(1024 * 1024, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        // the encoder and decoder are static as these are sharable
        pipeline.addLast(DECODER);
        pipeline.addLast(ENCODER);

        pipeline.addLast(socketServerHandler);
    }
}
```

Here is one part of the handler:

```
@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, byte[] msg) throws Exception {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(msg).asReadOnlyBuffer();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic is in this class

```
public class LogRecordDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) {

        LogRecord logRecord  = null;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[in.readableBytes()];
        int readerIndex = in.readerIndex();
        in.getBytes(readerIndex, bytes);

        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream inn = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(inn);
            logRecord  = (LogRecord) ois.readObject();
            out.add(logRecord);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```